# My NAT interface of VM can not ping out public network

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, nat

I have a Windows Server with two interface(one public interface 1, and a intranet interface 2) , I can communicate with public network(such as `8.8.8.8`) using the interface 1.

In my Windows Server 2008 I installed VMWare workstation, I have a `VMnet8` which use `NAT` mode.

```
name   mode  external-connection  host-connection   DHCP       subnet
VMnet8 NAT   NAT mode             connected         enbaled    192.168.42.0
```

The DHCP settings:

```
network: vmnet8
network IP: 192.168.42.0 
mask: 255.255.255.0
start IP: 192.168.42.128
end IP: 192.168.42.254
```

I have a vm with a interface using `VMnet8`:

```
network adapter 2 use VMnet8
```

I configured a IP address for it:

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

```
[root-localhost network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eno33554984
iWADDR=00：0c：Z9：4d：34：6b
rYPE=Ethernet
B00TPR0T0=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV&TNIT=yes
IPV6_AUT0C0NF=yes
IPV6_DEFR0UTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERR0UTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
1AME=eno33554984
DEVICE=eno33554984
DNB00T=yes
IPADDR=19Z.168.4Z.135
PREFIX=24
[root@locaIhost network-scripts]#
```

but I can not ping out `192.168.42.*`, can not ping `8.8.8.8`.
Is there anything gets wrong?

---

**EDIT-01**

in the vm I can not get the `8.8.8.8`, I only can get VMnet8's IP(the `192.168.42.1` is in the host machine):

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

My host server(VMnet8) address is the `192.168.42.1/24`:

My host server can ping out `8.8.8.8`:

why the vm's `192.168.42.135` can not communicate to Internet?

Comment: Check the Windows firewall of the Windows host system regarding incoming/outgoing ICMP. AFAIR by default both is forbidden on Windows Server.

Comment: Before ask this question I have closed firewall .

Comment: What does `ip r get 8.8.8.8` return?

Comment: I have updated my post, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not config the VMnet8's gateway in your VM's interface configuration file.

You should checkout the VMnet8's NAT setting to get the gateway of it, then config `GATEWAY` to your `ifcfg-eno33554984`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VMWare's document](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network21.html), the VMnet8's gateway and DNS server address is by default set as `192.168.<net>.2`，and the host is allocated with the address `192.168.<net>.1`.

If you set the interface's allocation methods as `manual`, you should also set the `GATEWAY` address as `192.168.<net>.2`. In addition, you can set the DNS server as `192.168.<net>.2` or other public DNS servers, such as, `8.8.8.8`.